nginx: динамическая подмена пути к файлу на основе части имени файла
Нужно динамическое преобразование путей к файлам следующего вида:
Исходный запрос: http://server.name/Application/77778945.png
Требуемый редирект: http://server.name/Application/png/7777/77778945.png
Есть ли возможность сделать это настройками конфигурации nginx-а?

Именно редирект или просто сразу файл отдать?

Но в общем директива rewrite справится, ничего сложного не вижу

Устроит и rewrite, вопрос в том, как с помощью PCRE преобразовать запрос.

А если длина имени файла (без учёта расширения) не 8 символов?

Длина в общем случае может быть произвольной. Нужно отделить от URL последний элемент пути и как-то (в map-е?) выделить 4 первых символа. Как замэпить расширение файла я примерно понимаю.

Например так https://regex101.com/r/sLjJAX/1

@Alexey Ten
Спасибо, у меня получилось не так изящно (через map), но тоже работает.
